# In array not ignoring file names

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my function I am trying to add the word **admin** here

```
$permission = 'admin' .'/'. strtolower(basename($file, '.php'));
```

But in my `$ignore = array()` the controllers names do not get ignored.

```
$ignore = array(
    'Dashboard',
    'Admin',
    'Logout',
    'Not_found',
    'Permission',
    'Footer',
    'Header',
    'Navbar',
    'Session_data'
);
```

**Question** when I add the word **admin** to the `$permission =` how can I make it ignore the controllers names are that in the ignore array.

```
$ignore = array(
    'Dashboard',
    'Admin',
    'Logout',
    'Not_found',
    'Permission',
    'Footer',
    'Header',
    'Navbar',
    'Session_data'
);

$data['permissions'] = array();

$files = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $permission = 'admin' .'/'. strtolower(basename($file, '.php'));

    if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
        $data['permissions'][] = $permission;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can first check and then add ` 'admin' .'/'. ` .right

Comment: if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
        $data['permissions'][] ='admin' .'/'. strtolower(basename($file, '.php'));
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify foreach as this..

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $permission = strtolower(basename($file, '.php'));

    if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
        $data['permissions'][] = 'admin' .'/'. $permission;
    }
}
```